# Dynamic buttons on a user form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to set up a small desktop application in C# what would read an xml file and based on the nodes inside the file it would generate buttons.

The XML file has the following nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
<version>1.0</version> 
<incident>
<template id="1">

  <name>some topic</name>
  <description>Use this for something</description>
  <item id="1">field 1</item>
  <item id="2">field 2</item>
  <item id="3">field 3</item>
  <item id="4">fiel 4</item>

</template>
```

I have a user form (Form1) with pre-defined buttons, it is working, but one of the buttons should read this xml file and open a new user form (Form3) with dinamically allocated buttons on it.

I have this code under the buton:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();

        var result = Username.Length <= 4 ? "" : Username.Substring(4);

        string path = $"C:\\Users\\{result}\\Documents\\template_manager\\config.xml";
        //MessageBox.Show(path);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(path);

        string string_title = "";
        while (xtr.Read())
        {
            if (xtr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xtr.Name == "name")
            {


                // string string_title = xtr.ReadElementString();
                string_title += xtr.ReadElementString() + Environment.NewLine;
               //MessageBox.Show("Title: " + Environment.NewLine + string_title);

                //var Form3 = new Form3(string_title);
                //Form3.show();
                Form3 frm3 = new Form3(string_title);
                {
                    frm3.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
```

On Form 3 I have the following code:

```
string dataFromForm1;
    public Form3(string data)
    {
        //getting Windows Logon ID from the system and assigning it to a string kind variable
        string Username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
        //-re-assigning windows logon ID to a variable
        //string str = Username;
        //Trimming the logon ID (removing "G0X/")
       string result = Username.Length <= 4 ? "" : Username.Substring(4);
        //passing the path of the xml file to a variable named path

        string path = $"C:\Users\\{result}\\Documents\\e2e_template_manager\\config.xml";
        //MessageBox.Show(path);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlNodeList templates = doc.SelectNodes(path);


        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;


        foreach (XmlNode template in templates)
        {
            string name = template.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText.Trim();
            Button button = new Button
            {
                Text = name,
                Left = x,
                Top = y
            };
            Controls.Add(button);
          y += button.Height + 5;
        }
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public void show()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Title: " + dataFromForm1);
    }

}
```

Could you help me on how t approach this problem? also the dinamicaly generated buttons should point at Form4 or Form5.

Comment: Windows Forms?  Or something else?

Comment: *generated buttons should point at Form4 or Form5*- it's not clear at all what you mean by this.

Comment: You seem to do it already, so what exactly is the problem? The code of the first form seems not to be relevant for this problem. Do you know that you can rename the forms to give them meaningful names?

Comment: Your code is far from being minimal. When you ask a question, you should always provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **Also, you don't really tell your problem or ask a question.** If you want help, then put some effort in your question.

Comment: Never hardcode a path to `Documents` like that. Always use functions like: `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a debugger to check where you have a problem in your code.** There are many things that could go wrong like incorrect path, incorrect file format, wrong arguments…

Some point about your code:

- Some variables start with an uppercase while others with a lowercase. While it does not matter for the compiler, it shows a lack of effort and consistency. You should usually follow Microsoft convention when writing C# code. I.e., fields, variables and parameters are camelCase, methods, properties and types are PascalCase.
- To improve readability, you can use verbatim interpolated string for `path` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Even better, use `System.Environment.GetFolderPath` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.2).
- <s>**Wrong item:** In C#, a string is created empty. No need to set `string_title` to an empty string.</s>
- **Alternative point:** Use a `StringBuilder` when building a string.
- Do you really want to create a new `Form3` for each node `name`?
- It looks like a `d`is missing in your input file: `<item id="4">fiel 4</item>`
- Have you ever read about **DRY principle** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)? The first 3 lines of `button1_Click`are the same as the first 3 lines of `Form3` constructor. Maker a function to get that path. It will make the code easier to maintain.

  - In `Form3` constructor, it seems that you are using `path` variable for 2 different purpose (file to load, XML path to a node) but using the same variable. **It is almost sure that you won't find any node!**
- `result` is a poor variable name. You should usually avoid it except for a variable that would contains to the result of the current function.
- I don't think it is a good idea to create your controls before the call to `InitializeComponent`. You should probably let WinForms create controls first then add yours.
- Why would you load the document both in the event handler and in the `Form3` constructor? You should probably pass the information already loaded to the constructor or probably better to a public function `LoadFromTemplate`.
- If `string_title` is really a title, then it should not contain a `Environment.NewLine`. If not, then a better name should be used.
- In any case, it is suspicious that it is a title for the caller and data for the new form.
- Also, you should not include `string_` as a prefix of your variable name. Hungarian notation is mainly considered obsolete with modern languages and IDE.
- You should give meaningful name to your forms.
- If you want to add event handler to your form, then simply add it after adding the button (and remove the handler when closing the form).
- Remove commented out code that is not useful for the question.

With modern IDE like Visual Studio that have good debugger, it is rarely useful to use `MessageBox` for tracing value. Simply put a breakpoint in your event handler and the step the code and inspect variables. For code like the above, **it should take less time to find the problem with the debugger** that it took you to write the question (or should have took if your question was **properly written** with **MCVE** and an actual **precise question**).

By the way, if the problem is loading the data, then any code related to opening a form is useless for the question. On the other hand, if the problem is displaying a form or a button, then any code related to loading the data is not necessary for the question. If you really have 2 problems, then ask 2 questions each one with **only the code relevant to one specific problem**.

**We do not do homework.** You must ask a specific question and not give us a bunch of code hoping that someone else will write the whole code for you.

**— Correction #2 —**

I was wrong for string initialization. So original code was correct for that point.

*Lately, I was doing C++, and the rules are very different!*

Comment: Your statement in point 3 is wrong! Local variables are not initialized by default. Class fields (and thus auto-properties) are initialized to `default(T)` where `T` is the type of the field. For reference types like `string` this is `null` (not empty string!).

Comment: **You are right**… When I was using C#, I use `StringBuilder` so I almost never need to initialize a string to empty and when I was doing it, I was using `string.Empty`.

Comment: Your correction is still wrong. Since `string_title` is a local variable, it is not assigned anything implicitly. You must initialize it explicitly to the desired value.

Comment: The [C# Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#local-variable-declarations) says *"A local variable must be definitely assigned (Definite assignment) at each location where its value is obtained."* and for [Initially unassigned variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#initially-unassigned-variables) *"Local variables, except those declared in a catch clause or a foreach statement"*

Comment: If you don't assign it a value before using it you get the compiler error *CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'string_title'*

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, you haven't stated what the problem is (what is not happening that you expecting to happen).  My guess is that your Form3 is not appearing.  It's not appearing because you're not telling it to appear.

```
//var Form3 = new Form3(string_title);
//Form3.show();
Form3 frm3 = new Form3(string_title);
{  // BTW: these braces are not necessary
    frm3.ShowDialog();
}
```

The commented out version is closer except you want to call [Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the Form you've created:

```
var frm3 = new Form3(string_title);
frm3.Show(this);  // ...and give it the parent window
```

Comment: `frm3.ShowDialog();` will show the form modally. He is telling it to appear so that isn't the problem.